# Explicit solution to $100(y + \frac{100}{10-y}) = x + 1000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
100\left(y + \frac{100}{10-y}\right) = x + 1000
$$

I'm looking to have the equation in the form $y(x) = ...$ Seems pretty simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

The answer is:

$$
y(x) = \frac{1}{200}\sqrt{x^2 + 4000x} − x
$$

Wolfram|Alpha returns a slightly different answer:
$$
y(x) = \frac{1}{200} (\sqrt{x^2+4000000}+x+2000)
$$

There must be something I'm missing. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha is correct. Starting with
$$100\left(y + \frac{100}{10-y}\right) = x + 1000$$
and dividing both sides by $100$:
$$y+\frac{100}{10-y}=\frac{x}{100}+10$$
multiplying both sides by $(10-y)$:
$$-y^2+10y+100=\left(\frac{x}{100}+10\right)(10-y)$$
collecting everything on one side:
$$y^2-\left(20+\frac{x}{100}\right)y+\frac{x}{10}=0$$
and then applying the quadratic formula gives
$$y=\frac{\left(20+\frac{x}{100}\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(20+\frac{x}{100}\right)^2-\frac{2x}{5}}}{2}=\frac{1}{200}\left(2000+x\pm\sqrt{(x+2000)^2-4000x}\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{200}\left(2000+x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4000000}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! Clever, I didn't realize one could us the quadratic formula for this purpose. Makes sense.

Comment: My textbook lists the first solution as the correct solution. Any chance you see how to go from the WolframAlpha solution to my textbook's solution? They don't seem equivalent to me.

Comment: @Gortaur: I'm afraid I don't see how that demonstrates they are equivalent. If we write
$$\frac{1}{200}\left(2000+x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4000000}\right) = \frac{1}{200}\sqrt{x^2 + 4000x} − x$$
then we get
$$2000+201x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4000000}=\sqrt{x^2+4000x}$$
and squaring both sides,
$$x^2+4000000+2(2000+201x)\sqrt{x^2+4000000}+(2000+201x)^2=x^2+4000x$$
which is impossible (there is a non-rational function on one side, and a [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) on the other). So, David, this demonstrates that they are indeed *not* equivalent.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: you're right, I made a thinko in my calculations.

Comment: Tremendously helpful. Thanks a lot to both of you for your time.